# PAW: The document could not be saved. An error occurred while saving

Tags: paw-app

*So I was adding and configuring some more requests in the .paw file I'm using to test our API, then at some point I thought it wasn't going to hurt to cmd+s ..*

[image: Error message when trying to save]

**The paw app is still open, the requests and conf still there, is there a way to actually save the changes ?**

Comment: Maybe try undoing things : Cmd + Z.

Comment: That's really weird, I've never seen this error for a long while. It happens sometimes when debugging but never seen that in production. Yeah, I think trying to undo things could help. Otherwise, you can manually export requests one by one using Pawprint: hit Cmd + / and it will sync your requests with our servers. Then if the app looses your data, you can still import again the requests one by one. Sorry that I don't have a better fix :(

Comment: Alright, I will take a look at the export/import